# How to get packet route in iOS OR get OSI model layer info in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sockets, networking

I am currently working on kind of network diagnostic application, In which I need to track packet rote with all IP address. I think this all information is in OSI model layer no. 3 network layer, but I am not able to extract this information.

I am using cocoaasyncsocket library to create sockets also I am able to send and receive data but did not get how to extract layer information. Below is how I am using cocoaasyncsocket.

```
// To send data
char bytes[] = "abcd\r\n";
NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
[socket writeData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:0];


// To read data
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{
    NSString* newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];    
    NSLog(@"socket socketDidReadData:%@", newStr);
}
```

[In this link apple say packet tracing is not possible on iPhone, but I am still not sure.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1176/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001707-CH1)
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1176/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001707-CH1

Below is diagram what I need to draw something like this on iPhone. I am trying since last two days and able to get any other information related to do this.

[image]

[I found a solution but It’s require a MAC system and also a MAC app which will grab this info and then send to iPhone via USB cable.](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/remote-packet-capture-for-ios-devices/)
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/remote-packet-capture-for-ios-devices/

Any helpful link, information can save my days.

Comment: check if some web-service is available for it

Comment: I don't think so, It's not possible via web-services.

Comment: it's hundred percent possible, check if there is already available free service is there or not. if not you can ask server side developer to do so

Comment: I need to check route from iPhone to any server(like ping), and web-services will be on server. So If we using services then how can they trace route from iPhone to server, they will do like server to server route not iPhone to server. And I am working on dignostic app what if there is not connection. Finally the thing is I need to extract OSI model layers on iOS device.

Comment: FYI: the OSI model for network communications is only a model.  No network stack on the planet implements all the layers, and stacks will not necessarily keep the layers separated according to the model.  Thus, the idea of getting information from a specific layer is meaningless.  Specify exactly which information you want, and perhaps someone will be able to direct you.

Comment: I only need the route of packets, like in above image IP address of all routers.

Comment: Read about how tracerouting works.  There is no layer that can tell you the route of a packet.  The very basic idea is that a packet is constructed with a max number of hops.  The device doing the tracing gets a response from the last hop and records the responder.  Then, another packet is sent out, with the max hops increased by one.  This is done until the final host is finally reached.